# Microsoft Calendar "We couldn't find your settings. Error code: 0x80070490

Tags: windows-error-reporting

[image: The error]

What was tried: [https://www.technipages.com/fix-error-0x80070490-we-couldnt-find-your-settings/#:~:text=Windows%2010%20Mail%20App%20error,and%20repair%20your%20system%20files](https://www.technipages.com/fix-error-0x80070490-we-couldnt-find-your-settings/#:%7E:text=Windows%2010%20Mail%20App%20error,and%20repair%20your%20system%20files).

Side note: running on a fresh install of Windows

Comment: See if this article helps:   https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-mail-0x80070490-error/#:~:text=You%20might%20be%20encountering%20the,as%20we%20have%20shown%20below.

Comment: Updating worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I post an answer.  Since this worked you may wish to acknowledge my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article:

[Fix Microsoft Calendar error](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-mail-0x80070490-error/#:%7E:text=You%20might%20be%20encountering%20the,as%20we%20have%20shown%20below)

Outdated Mail app - your Mail app might be outdated, which is causing some of its features to act up. The solution, in this case, is simple, as all that you need to do is update the application to get it up and running again.